# Publishing Play Modules - Folder structure requirements

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

When publishing play modules (I'm only trying to publish locally for now), is it required to have a certain folder structure? I've tried renaming my app folder to src and it publishes fine, but after I've referenced the package in my build.sbt file, the compiler can't find the packages. When I rename the folder back to app, everything works fine.

Comment: Are you publishing a full play application as a module, or just a library that includes play during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

A Module is a micro-Play App (controllers, views, etc), whereas a Plugin will be code that gets loaded in at runtime and provides some sort of fucntionality to the app.

Modules will be Play Projects with a very strict structure by default. While it's possible to overwrite these values by modifying the settings in your Buildfile, the best practice tends to be maintaining this structure.

- All source goes in **/App**,
- Application configuration and general resources in **/Conf**
- Build settings in **/Project**
- Static resources usually go in **/Public** though that's configurable as part of the routes.

#### Some modules include plugins; a good example of this is [SecureSocial](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/module-code) - you can see it follows the standard Play project structure, but also includes plugins like [IdentityProvider and its subclasses](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/IdentityProvider.scala)

Let's take a moment and look at what's involved in building the plugin side of things:

#### Creating  a plugin:

This involves a few steps:

- Create a class that extends play.api.Plugin; this class should contain any initialization logic you need or want to perform; think of it like a module-specific GlobalSettings.

An example from Plugins.scala:

```
class MyPlugin(app: Application) extends Plugin {
    override def onStart() = {
    Logger.info("Plugin started!")
  }
}
```

- Create a **play.plugins** file in your conf directory that references that class; with a priority. That will cause the plugin to be loaded onStart.
- Set up your routes and controllers and views as normal; they can be referenced just like you'd expect.

[Deabolt-2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala) - A standard module without any plugins.

[Play-JDBC](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main) - A plugin that's included with Play

hope that provides some insight into the various options you have for building reusable, shareable Play code.

Happy developing!